# Conditional DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Here is what I am trying to do.  I have 2 Data Templates defined which both refer to a different user control.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate1">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <myUserControl1 />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate2">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                <myUserControl2/>
            </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I am using these Data Templates to display a list of items using ItemsControl like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="myItemList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myDataTemplate1}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate />
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

I would like the ItemTemplate to conditionally be either myDataTemplate1 or myDataTemplate1 depending on the value of an integer variable being 1 or 2 respectively.

Should I use DataTriggers for this or is there another way to do this? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Don't set the `ItemTemplate` but use an [`ItemTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx).

`DataTriggers` would be fine too of course, spares you the extra class for the selector. e.g.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ThatProperty}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                                    Value="{StaticResource myDataTemplate1}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ThatProperty}" Value="2">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                                    Value="{StaticResource myDataTemplate2}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I did not realize it was legal to set a ContentTemplate with a DataTemplate? How does that work?

Comment: @blue18hutthutt: `ContentTemplate` is just a property which could have any type, in this case the type is `DataTemplate` as can be seen in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplate.aspx) as well. Not to be confused with `ControlTemplate` which is also a type of template which is used with the [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) property. Also there are analogous properties: `ContentControl`->`ContentTemplate` & `ItemsControl`->`ItemTemplate`.

Comment: That's where the confusion stems from :) Come to think of it ..that also explains alot of other confusion from the past too!