# WPF Combobox issue

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combo box in a wpf c# application. In the xaml i am trying to do the following.

The ItemsSource comes from one variable.
SelectedItem sets a value on another variable

But i want the text displayed to come from a new variable.

How do i stop making the selected itemssource appear as the main text?

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboPlay" FontSize="14" MinHeight="20" Margin="0,2,4,4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" MinWidth="160"
ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxList}"
SelectedItem="{Binding OutputChannel.Value, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ValueToStringConverter}}" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
IsEnabled="{Binding IsDriveChoiceEnabled}"
HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see your ViewModel-code ;)

Comment: What do you mean by 'channel'? Also, please explain what you mean by 'How do i stop making the selected itemssource appear as the main text?'

Answer (score 1):

If you mean changing the display of the item currently selected (the portion of the control shown when the dropdown is closed), take a look at [Can I use a different Template for the selected item in a WPF ComboBox than for the items in the dropdown part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672867/can-i-use-a-different-template-for-the-selected-item-in-a-wpf-combobox-than-for)

Honestly, a quick search dug up that one and many similar ones. Probably the simplest way, like the linked answer, is to figure out if your item is wrapped in a ComboBoxItem and display it differently then. Or you could re-template the ComboBox. Or you could derive from it (and re-template it) and provide a separate dependency property for the template of the selected item, if you expect to reuse it in different contexts. The sky's the limit.