# How can I bind to a property from the Selected Item of a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I am attempting to create a user control for the purposes of allowing a user to define their own custom linear gradient within an application.

So far I have a user control which makes use of the following model for defining a collection of Gradient Stops :

```
public class StopSelectorModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    #region Field Values
    private Task _PropertyT;
    private ObservableCollection<GradientStop> _Stops;
    private GradientStop _SelectedStop;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set Gradient Stop Collection.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<GradientStop> Stops {
        get { return this._Stops; }
        set {
            this._Stops = value;
            this._SelectedStop = value.FirstOrDefault( );

            this._PropertyT = Task.WhenAll( new Task[ ] {
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "Stops" ),
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "SelectedStop" )
            } );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set Selected Gradient Stop.
    /// </summary>
    public GradientStop SelectedStop {
        get { return this._SelectedStop; }
        set {
            if ( value == null )
                return;

            if ( !this._Stops.Contains( value ) )
                this._Stops.Add( value );
            this._SelectedStop = value;

            this._PropertyT = this.OnPropertyChanged( "SelectedStop" );
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    protected async Task OnPropertyChanged( string P ) {
        if ( this.PropertyChanged != null )
            await this.PropertyChanged.Async( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( P ) );
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// Declare instance of StopSelectorModel.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Base">GradientStopCollection to wrap.</param>
    public StopSelectorModel( ObservableCollection<GradientStop> Base ) { this.Stops = Base; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Declare default instance of StopSelectorModel.
    /// </summary>
    public StopSelectorModel( ) : this( new ObservableCollection<GradientStop>( new GradientStop[ ] {
        new GradientStop( Colors.White, 0.0D ),
        new GradientStop( Colors.Black, 1.0D )
    } ) ) { }
    #endregion
}
```

I use this as a DataContext for a ComboBox ( ItemSource = Stops, SelectedItem = SelectedStop, two-way binding, standard operating procedure for something like this as far as I am aware ).

I also have a control which uses the following Color Model to define colors ( 4 slide bars basically ) :

```
/// <summary>
/// Wrapper for allowing complete databinding of a System.Windows.Media.Color struct.
/// </summary>
public class ColorModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private Task _PropertyT;
    private Color _Color;

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set Context Color.
    /// </summary>
    public Color Color {
        get { return this._Color; }
        set {
            this._Color = value;
            this._PropertyT = Task.WhenAll( new Task[ ] {
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "Color" ),
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "ScA" ),
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "ScR" ),
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "ScG" ),
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "ScB" ),
            } );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set Color ScA value.
    /// </summary>
    public double ScA {
        get { return this._Color.ScA; }
        set {
            this._Color.ScA = ( float )value;
            this._PropertyT = Task.WhenAll( new Task[ ] {
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "Color" ),
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "ScA" ),
            } );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set Color ScR value.
    /// </summary>
    public double ScR {
        get { return this._Color.ScR; }
        set {
            this._Color.ScR = ( float )value;
            this._PropertyT = Task.WhenAll( new Task[ ] {
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "Color" ),
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "ScR" ),
            } );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set Color ScG value.
    /// </summary>
    public double ScG {
        get { return this._Color.ScG; }
        set {
            this._Color.ScG = ( float )value;
            this._PropertyT = Task.WhenAll( new Task[ ] {
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "Color" ),
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "ScG" ),
            } );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set Color ScB value.
    /// </summary>
    public double ScB {
        get { return this._Color.ScB; }
        set {
            this._Color.ScB = ( float )value;
            this._PropertyT = Task.WhenAll( new Task[ ] {
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "Color" ),
                this.OnPropertyChanged( "ScB" ),
            } );
        }
    }

    protected async Task OnPropertyChanged( string P ) {
        await this.PropertyChanged?.Async(
            this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( P ) ).DontBlock( );
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Define ColorModel with default White Color.
    /// </summary>
    public ColorModel( ) : this( Colors.White ) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Define ColorModel with provided color.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="C">Color to assign to ColorModel.</param>
    public ColorModel( Color C ) { this.Color = C; }
}
```

So here we are... how can I tie the Color property of the SelectedItem of my ComboBox together with this ColorModel? ( Will furnish more details if/as necessary but sort of short on time ).

Thank you for your help in advance...

### EDIT 1

For a bit of clarity - I want to pass the SelectedValue ( Color ) to a control which will be able to edit that color.

So the order of operations would be to have the ComboBox select one of the Gradient Stops, and then ( and this is where I need help ) the control which is responsible for adjusting the color values.

Comment: why are you having all those async calls on OnPopertyChanged??

Comment: @Steve While not relevant to my question or the problem, they are there for no reason in particular. It's just a preference of mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you right you want to get chosen gradient color shown when item is chosen.

I would go with creating own DataTemplate for it with setting color as a binding for run time build color in GradientStop. Depending if you want all your combobox items colored or not this might be helpful: [Can I use a different Template for the selected item in a WPF ComboBox than for the items in the dropdown part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672867/can-i-use-a-different-template-for-the-selected-item-in-a-wpf-combobox-than-for)

**Edit**

In response to edit: if I understand it right you've got UserControl with DataContext being some UserControlModel, which on of childrens is StopSelectorModel, in that case I would go with raising event on SelectedGradientStop is set and handling this event in UserControlModel.

Or, if it's not children-parent relation I would use Messanger and send message whenever SelectedGradientStop is set.

Both event and message would have to contain object describing what color should be used.

Comment: No. That's not right. I want to be able to pass the Color value to a control which will be used to edit the colors properties. I will clarify in my question...