# ComboBox.SelectedValue returns ToString() instead of the Name property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am trying to make a `ComboBox` where the drop-down list shows the name and description of the campaign elements (properties `NombreCampana` and `Descripcion` of class `Campana`) and when you select one value it shows the Name (`NombreCampana`). I have done this with an `ObservableCollection` so the changes affect the `ComboBox` without reloading.

In the MainMenu window (`menuPrincipal`), I have this XAML for the `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox Style="{DynamicResource comboBoxCampaign}"
            x:Name="campaignComboBox"
            Text="{DynamicResource CampaignList}"                 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nombres}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=NombreCampana, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedValuePath="Value"
            SelectionChanged="CampaigneComboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}&#x0a;{1}">
                        <Binding Path="NombreCampana"/>
                        <Binding Path="Descripcion"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The `ComboBox`, is linked to an `ObservableCollection` in the code-behind:

```
        private List<Campana> listacampana = new List<Campana>();
        private ObservableCollection<Campana> nombres = new ObservableCollection<Campana>();

        public ObservableCollection<Campana> Nombres
        {
            get { return nombres; }
            set { nombres = value; }
        }

        public List<Campana> ListaCampanas
        {
            get { return listacampana; }
            set { listacampana = value; }
        }


        public menuPrincipal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ConfiguracionPagina.DefinirIdioma(this, "MainMenu");

            this.listacampana.AddRange(MainWindow.DatosUsuario.ListCampaigns);

            foreach (Campana item in this.listacampana)
            {
                this.nombres.Add(item);
            }

            campaignComboBox.ItemsSource = this.nombres;

        }
```

That code defines the language, changes the texts, adds the user list to the property list, and after that adds to the all the items `Campana` (campaign) to the `ObservableCollection`.

After that I set the `ItemSource` of the `ComboBox` to `Nombres` (the `ObservableCollection`).

The class `Campana` is:

```
public class Campana
{
    private string nombre;
    private string descripcion;
    private string imagen;
    private List<RecursosCampana> listarecursos = new List<RecursosCampana>();

    public string DireccionImagen
    {
        get { return imagen; }
        set { imagen = value; }
    }

    public List<RecursosCampana> RecursosCampana
    {
        get { return listarecursos; }
        set { listarecursos = value; }
    }

    public string Descripcion
    {
        get { return descripcion; }
        set { descripcion = value; }
    }

    public string NombreCampana
    {
        get { return nombre; }
        set { nombre = value; }
    }
}
```

When I run the application, the `DataTemplate` works fine and shows the items with the description.
[image: The dropdown list of the combobox]

But when I select one item I get this:
[image: The item selected showing the Object.tostring()]

I have tried everything that I founded by searching Google, but I don't get what is happening. Also, if I don't define the `ItemSource` in the code, the XAML `ItemSource` doesn't work. This is what happens if I comment out `campaignComboBox.ItemsSource = this.nombres;`:
[image: if i comment campaignComboBox.ItemsSource = this.nombres;]

Edit: answering the comments, i have solved thanks to @Keith Stein, a part of the problem, this was the style

```
<Style x:Key="comboBoxCampaign" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
    </Style>
```

I used that to have a "placeholder" text, an initial text which is going to dissapears once you click in the combobox, when i delete "IsEditable" i lost the initial title the combobox just have the V to press, but now when i select an item, i get the name + description.

[image: After select one item]

Is not exactly what i want, i just want to show the name, but is more close to that.

Edit2: The problem with the databinding was that i didnt use the DataContext = this; now i can get the bind from xaml but still i cant show just the name.

Lastly answering to the last comment, what i am trying to do is:
- I'm doing an application to prepare roleplaying adventures or scenarios, in this section the user select the campaign that he is going to use, so i want that when he press the combobox, he can see the name of the campaign and the description because he could have 2 similar campaigns or based in the same system, and once he choose one, just show the name that is more elegant specially if he writes a big description

Comment: I don't see anything that would mess up the `DataTemplate` or the selected item, unless there's something in the `comboBoxCampaign` `Style`?

Comment: There is a `public ObservableCollection<Campana> Nombres` property, so `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nombres}"` will obviously work, provided that the DataContext of the view is set to an instance of the class that owns the Nombres property, i.e. `DataContext = this;`. However, `SelectedValuePath="Value"` and `SelectedValue="{Binding Path=NombreCampana}"` make no sense, because there is neither a `Value` property in class Campana, nor a `NombreCampana` property in  class menuPrincipal. It is also totally unclear why you bind the Text property of the ComboBox.

Comment: I have edit the post and answer your question Clemens, and i show the style, deleting one property of the style helps but is not exactly what i want but at least is an improve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i get the answer in this post [Can I use a different Template for the selected item in a WPF ComboBox than for the items in the dropdown part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672867/can-i-use-a-different-template-for-the-selected-item-in-a-wpf-combobox-than-for)

Simple swapping between two templates if the item is selected or not.