# How should I set a ComboBox ControlTemplate's property based on its TemplatedParent's ItemSource's property?

Tags: wpf, controltemplate

My ComboBox has a DataTemplate. I refer to this
[Can I use a different Template for the selected item in a WPF ComboBox than for the items in the dropdown part?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672867/can-i-use-a-different-template-for-the-selected-item-in-a-wpf-combobox-than-for) because my request is similar to it:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                    Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
                    Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxControlTemplate}"
                    ItemTemplateSelector="{UI:ComboBoxTemplateSelector
                    SelectedItemTemplate={StaticResource ComboBoxSelectedItemDataTemplate},
                    DropdownItemsTemplate={StaticResource ComboBoxDataTemplate}}"/>
```

It works well but I got another request: To set the `ComboBox`'s `ToggleButton`'s `Background` based on `SelectedItem`. So I right click this `ComboBox` in the designer page, choose

> Edit Template -> Edit a Copy

to generate an automatic template. In the automatically generated template I get:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
  <ToggleButton>
    <Border x:Name="splitBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" ...>
      <Path x:Name="Arrow" .../>
    </Border>
  </ToggleButton>
</ControlTemplate>
```

So what I want to change in the above code is `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"`. I want the `Background` to be based on an **ItemSource ViewModel property** called `SelectedName` just like in `DataTemplate` I have something like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxSelectedItemDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        ...
        <TextBlock Background="{Binding Converter="{StaticResource StringToColorConverter}", Path="SelectedName"}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I searched quite a few but not sure what I should do to achieve this. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Background` property of the `ComboBox` similar to how you set the `Background` of the `TextBlock`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" ...
          Background="{Binding SelectedItem.SelectedName, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource StringToColorConverter}}">
```

The above binds the `Background` property to the `SelectedName` property of the currently selected item of the `ComboBox`.