# how to do I show two displaymemeber and one selected value path in a combobox c# wpf only left one

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF C#

I want to show DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath in a Combobox item
but when the user clicked on one of the Combobox items, then on the Combobox selected item showing just SelectedValue

Like this Emulated picture :
[image]

My Model:

```
    public partial class CST
{
    public string Tafcode { get; set; }//ID
    public string Esm { get; set; }//Name

    public string Shoy => $"{Tafcode}  {Esm}";
}
```

CS :

```
  var quer_ITM = dbms.Database.SqlQuery<CST>("SELECT Tafcode , Esm FROM CST").ToList();

        cmb.ItemsSource = quer_ITM;
        cmb.DisplayMemberPath = "Shoy"; //Merg of Esm + Tafcode
        cmb.SelectedValuePath = "Tafcode";//The Primary Key 112-1-1
```

XAML:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmb"  Margin="0,312,202,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  FontFamily="/Negin;component/NT/#IRANSans" IsEditable="True" Background="#FFCCFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="402">
       
    </ComboBox>
```

I have no error in the up lines, just I don't know how to do that

Please Help ?

Comment: You can do this via templating. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672867/can-i-use-a-different-template-for-the-selected-item-in-a-wpf-combobox-than-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace the `DisplayMemberPath` with an `ItemTemplate`:

```
cmb.ItemsSource = dbms.Database.SqlQuery<CST>("SELECT Tafcode , Esm FROM CST").ToList();
...
<ComboBox x:Name="cmb"  Margin="0,312,202,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" 
        FontFamily="/Negin;component/NT/#IRANSans" IsEditable="True" Background="#FFCCFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="402"
        SelectedValuePath="SelectedValuePath">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Shoy}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

...and override the `ToString()` method of your class:

```
public partial class CST
{
    public string Tafcode { get; set; }
    public string Esm { get; set; }

    public string Shoy => $"{Tafcode}  {Esm}";

    public override string ToString() => Tafcode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks That's Solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot directly define the manipulation operator with the same class members. You either have to write a small helper function to do this
Try changing your code to
cmb.DisplayMemberPath = $"{Tafcode}  {Esm}";