How can I create a combobox with buttons next to the items?
I would like to create a combobox with "remove" buttons next to the combobox items. But I don't know how can I remove (or hide) the button next to the selected item.
image about my problem
I tried to solve it like this:
        <ComboBox Height="25" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnRemove" Content="remove" Click="btnRemove_Click"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>


Here are some ideas. (I prefer "smart" data objects; one that would "know" it was selected). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672867/can-i-use-a-different-template-for-the-selected-item-in-a-wpf-combobox-than-for
